# About GridView: getView() auto called from first position to last

Tags: android, call

Puzzle~~~I have come across a strange problem. That is once my activity init, the gridView will call the getView() method to init all the items in it. But I haven't done any event, I haven't even touched the screen, but the gridview does really load the picture from the first position to the last. Here is my log:

```
D/LocalGridViewAdapter(20843): getView() called at :0
D/LocalGridViewAdapter(20843): getView() called at :0
D/LocalGridViewAdapter(20843): getView() called at :1
D/LocalGridViewAdapter(20843): getView() called at :2
D/LocalGridViewAdapter(20843): getView() called at :3
D/LocalGridViewAdapter(20843): getView() called at :4
       .....................................
D/LocalGridViewAdapter(20843): getView() called at :564
D/LocalGridViewAdapter(20843): getView() called at :565
```

And I thought that is caused by ViewTreeObserver, but I do need it to resize the layout of the gridview item, make the picture look more beautiful. Here is the code of my ViewTreeObserver, it is from Google bitmapFun Projext:

```
gv.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
    new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            if (mAdapter.getNumColumns() == 0) {
                final int numColumns = (int) Math.floor(gv.getWidth()
                    / (GlobalConstants.mImageThumbSize 
                    + GlobalConstants.mImageThumbSpacing));
                if (numColumns > 0) {
                    final int columnWidth = (gv.getWidth() / numColumns)
                        - GlobalConstants.mImageThumbSpacing;
                    GlobalConstants.reqSize = columnWidth;
                    mAdapter.setNumColumns(numColumns);
                    mAdapter.setItemHeight(columnWidth);
                    Log.d("~~~~~~~~~~~",
                        "onCreateView - numColumns set to " + numColumns);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

I just doubt why Bitmapfun is okay? It works well, but my project goes bad.

Answer (score 0):

There have been many people with this problem already asked on SO. I am working with ListView with my custom Adapter too. And I can assure you that,

> There is absolutely no guarantee on the number of times getView() will be invoked for any given position

I my case, the `ListView` also called all `getView()` function from the start to the end, then it call it again from 0 to 3 (for on my phone, 4 items are on the screen). Anyway, it's always good to make your `getView` doing things as fast as possible, because it will also be called when you scroll your `GridView`, and no one can tell you which position will be given.

**EDIT:**
The most important part is the one I put in the box. I have little uses of `GridView` before, but I suppose its behaviours are mostly the same on `ListView`, since both of them use recycled `View`s and `Adapter`. After looked at your comment, I tested on my phone and my friend's phone for both `GridView` and `ListView`, and realize a great difference:

- On my phone, `ListView` and `GridView` both call `getView()` at the init for all the items, and then call `getView()` again for the items that are on the screen.
- On my friend's phone, only the shown items are called by the `getView()`.

Can I conclude that it is OS-dependent? And my conclusion is correct, I believe you should not consider the `ViewTreeObserver` into your problem.

Comment: E,,if i delete the ViewTreeObserver of GridView, and give it a fixed dp or pixel, it won't call getView from the first to the last once it is inited. But i want to use the observer to change the size of the gridView item accordint to the different screens. And in the project BitmapFun of Google, which has use observer to do this ,but it does't come across this problem.i just cant fingure it out

Comment: I was just curious since my phone was not the same as what you said. So I borrowed my friend's phone (Android 4.2), mine is 4.0.4. I edit my answer according to the result.

Comment: i just don't want it to do that ,cause there are 500+ images, it will take a lot time to load them all. just load the images on the current screen~ that is what i want